Can a power cord running through a metal fitting induce voltage?
When I dug out an old floor lamp, I decided to run some basic "safety" checks using a multimeter. To my surprise I measured some voltage on the lamp post and I believe that this voltage is caused by induction.
The post contains a metal (probably iron) joint or fitting similar in geometry to this one:
.
Its diameter is about 1 cm and its length is about 3 cm. The power cord (2 lines, 240V, 50Hz) runs axial through this joint.
At the joint I measure 38 V against ground if the lamp is turned off and 60 V when the lamp is turned on.
Can it be that this voltage is caused by induction and (how much) should I worry about it?
Edit: I did some additional measurements and got: 70V with lamp on, 60V without lamp, and 38V with one line turned off. Current is between 5 and 7 µA.

Tip: "Power cord". A "power chord" is used by rock guitarists! The fitting in the picture is brass, not iron.

Thx and sry for the spelling ;) Yes, the pictured fitting is most likely brass. It is similar to my iron fitting in shape and geometry but not color.


Can it be that this voltage is caused by induction and (how much)
should I worry about it?

It could be capacitance, very sensitive multimeters can detect very small currents and they can be small enough to be transmitted through air and insulation gaps.
One check that I do is see if there is an current. Start with the 10A mode on the meter with AC currents, and check it with respect to a good ground (not on the lamp). If there is next to no current then you are fine. If you see mA of current you probably have a problem and you are getting leakage somewhere and it's not safe.

I measured the following: 70V 2.4A with lamp on, 60V 2A without lamp, 38V 1.2A with one line turned off. Seems a bit high?!?

Yeah that is way too high, you have leakage somewhere.  Turn the lamp off and ohm out the body to the terminals, its likely you have a intermediate short. Currents that high are not safe.

Yes, I currently dont trust this thing. I could not measure any short (resistance) using the multimeter though.

1A is crazy high,  have an insulation test done

Sorry, I messed up. The plugs on the multimeter need to be switched for current measurement. I now get between 5 and 7 µA. Thank you for your help!!

It is capacitance.
Two conductive elements with insulator between them is a capacitor.
A mains live wire, that is insulated, and running inside a metal pipe, is an axial capacitor.
I also have a lamp with such a construction and can feel the lamp cord being plugged in depending on how my finger slides on the metal pipe. Sometimes you get the same effect with ungrounded two-prong laptop power bricks, especially with laptops that have a metal or otherwise conductive shell. Or with grounded power bricks that are plugged into ungrounded outlets in an old building.
Depending on which wire (or both) the lamp switch is on, and the switch position, there will be different length of wire energized and thus different amount of capacitive coupling between mains wire and metal pipe. 60VAC is almost nothing, it could be more.
It's normal. You should not worry about it too much, it is just disturbing and annoying but not dangerous. The capacitive coupling is relatively small and weak.
It only gets dangerous if you are able to measure resistance between the metal pipe and mains plug terminals. For safety, it's not a bad idea to touch any metallic ungrounded electrical device with one hand only, if there happens to be a fault in the device and the metal parts are live.

Thanks for your answer! I tested for resistance and there is no connection between the metal fitting and any of the wires.

"Can a power cord running through a metal fitting induce voltage?'
No but the metal pipes connecting can act as antenna to the electric field or e-field that is everywhere in a home.   With enough wire and big coils, you might be able to make a LED glow faintly in the dark.
No worries, yes both electric and perhaps magnetic fields but very small current below your sensation levels.
The electric field created by a single-line wire is proportional to its length. The coupling must be close to the pipe to do this. From your two measurements, this indicates it is a high-impedance very low current. It is altered by both the current via induction of the H-field from the current and the E-field for voltage coupling by the tiny capacitance (<100 pF) between the insulated wires and air to the tube when the current is off.
Depending on the location of the switch, it could also be all e-field coupling as the length of the voltage applied may rise to the lamp and thus increase the nearby e-field within the pole.
The impedance must be higher than the standard DMM impedance of 1 Megohm because you got much less than 50% of the 230V line voltage.
This means it was reading 60 microamps or 0.06 mA which is far less than the typical 2.5 mA trip level of leakage detection devices such as RCDs, so it is very safe.
To verify this yourself you can probably alter the readings just by holding the lamp pole and the capacitance of your body to air might raise or lower the reading. 230V  E-fields pass right through your body from line frequency without you ever even feeling it. That may sound spooky but your body also makes a good AM antenna with your hand around an AM radio antenna on a weak signal.  This is normal and also in the range of microamps and does not affect the body.
It is current that is the measure of a sensation and in this case safety.  So you can measure the current to verify yourself.
When we first started using scope probes, we learned how to generate the same voltage just by touching the probe tip and not the ground clip which would shunt the low current very fast by suppressing the e-field on the finger touching the probe ground. Yet there was never any sensation.  Laptop chargers are much worse since they conduct noise and are not PE grounded and you can feel what is deemed safe as a tingle on your wrist until the laptop is grounded say through an LED display cable or equivalent grounded path.
